# Python Queue doc says "if empty() returns False it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to get() will not block"

Tags: python, queue

I don't understand why when the Queue is not empty, there should be any block to get from it ?

btw. that quote is coming from the [Queue doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it's not guarantteed that between the call to `empty` and the next call to `get` another thread may not have already pulled an element from the queue emptying it. Therefore the next call to `get` can block.